# TCL wait for exec background job to finish

Tags: tcl, exec, pid

How do I get notification that a job that I launched in TCL via exec has finished?

```
set pid [ exec job & ]
while {<some_magic>} {puts "" waiting for $pid to finish ; sleep 1}
puts "Job $pid has finished. Now let's collect results."
```

The whole idea is that in reality I want to launch many jobs and then need to monitor when they're done.

Your feedback is much appreciated.

Best,
Gert

Comment: See [detect-end-of-tcl-background-process-in-a-tcl-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112376/detect-end-of-tcl-background-process-in-a-tcl-script).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Unix, the result of `exec` is a process ID. There are all sorts of ways of checking whether a process exists; one of the neatest is to do:

```
set running [file exists /proc/$pid]
```

But that's not portable. (It works on Linux and, IIRC, Solaris. It doesn't work on OSX, and it's not meaningful at all on Windows of course.)

Another approach is to do:

```
set finished [catch {exec ps -p $pid >/dev/null}]
# Note the inverted sense of result compared with previous code sample
```

This works on any Unix that has `ps` (i.e., all of them) and where that `ps` accepts `-p` to mean “just talk about the following process ID”. So if you're running on BSD (other than OSX, where I've tested it), you might have problems. *Test it!*

Apart from that, you can also use the TclX extension's `signal` command to detect a `SIGCHLD` and act on that.

---

The most portable method of all (i.e., works on Windows and all Unixes) is to use `open` to make a pipeline and then use `fileevent` to detect the termination of the process. See this Stack Overflow question for more details: [Detect end of TCL background process in a TCL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112376/detect-end-of-tcl-background-process-in-a-tcl-script)

Comment: If have coded the 'ps' solution which works fine, but will try the /proc/$pid. That one is quite elegant and as I am on centos linux it will be OK. Thanks, Gert.

Comment: [file exists /proc/$pid] this function always returns true, that means my exec process is runs in background for forever? am i correct ? if not please correct me

Comment: @mf_starboi_8041 that's because tcl does not reap zombie processes. I'm looking for a solution to that problem too.